# where can i find in reflector the initiations of a Page?

Tags: asp.net

if i have

```
public partial class MyLittlePage: System.Web.UI.Page
{...
```

and i have overriden **for example** the **OnLoad**...

my question :  where in the code(reflector) does the compiler creates this :

```
  System.Web.UI.Page= new MyLittlePage(); ??
```

i want to see all the chain of the polymorphic affect..
(or in other words : i'm overloading **OnLoad** for **what** virtual function ? )

i know  the virtual function is on the Control Page
but i **wasn't** able to see the Polymorphic creation pattern of :

```
Class1 x = new Class2();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the depths of ASP.NET 4...

1. `HttpApplication` uses the nested `MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep` class to populate `HttpContext.Handler` from an `IHttpHandlerFactory`.
2. Through a layer of caching, requests for `Page` (and all types implementing `IHttpHandler`) use an instance of `System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryWrapper`.
3. `HandlerFactoryWrapper.GetHandler()` in turn calls `HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance()`, which uses `Activator.CreateInstance()` to instantiate the class.

Comment: so , there is an existing mechanism of Polymorphism ??? thanks , could find much info about this... wonder why....?

Comment: In this case polymorphism is used in that whatever `IHttpHandler` a request maps to (`Page`, web service, etc), the runtime just needs to call `ProcessRequest()` on any of them.